# The XML file in optaplanner nurse scheduling system can interact with the front desk in real time

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am using your `optaplanner` as a doctor scheduling system.

I have a question for you:

I use optaplanner as a backend system, passing the XML file to optaplanner through PHP, and returning the calculated XML results to the PHP backend system by optaplanner. Now I want the doctor to see the change in the web page in real time. Can I make it happen? It is to enable optaplanner to produce XML files in real time instead of generating XML files that are calculated at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but it would likely require you to change up your architecture a bit.

For sending results from the server to the client (the user's browser) you'd want to use websockets.

Optaplanner has the SolverEventListener which gets called everytime the best solution changes. What you can do is send out the solution over a websocket everytime bestSolutionChanged is called in the listener. For performance reasons you will probably want the websocket send request to be a nonblocking operation and the serialization of your solution should happen fast. You probably also want to include a minimum time between each webocket send request/bestSolutionChanged call, since in the beginning Optaplanner will likely frequently find a new best solution.

I don't know how you'd do this in PHP, but generally for such types of realtime applications vert.x has been a good fit for me (the optaplanner solution calculation is handled in a worker verticle, new solutions are sent out over the eventbus through a sockjs eventbus bridge)

Comment: PHP is mainly used to receive my XML file in real time, and then interact with the page by PHP. My main task is to generate the XML files in real time to PHP, and the other is the interaction between the PHP and the page.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly implemented it like Alex G described it.

As our solution can get quite big I just send out a websocket event that a new best solution is available and let the application request the solution instead of serializing and pushing the full solution every time a new best solution is found.

To get xml:

If i had to do that ( i prefer json for being smaller and easier to process in a javascript frontend) my approach would be the following steps:

1) Create a SolverEventListener class

```
class SolverEventListenerImpl implements SolverEventListener<ProblemSolutionClass> {...
```

2) register the eventListener in the solver

```
solver.addEventListener(new SolverEventListenerImpl());
```

3) overwrite the bestSolutionChanged method

```
public void bestSolutionChanged( BestSolutionChangedEvent<ProblemSolutionClass> event) {      
  ProblemSolutionClass solution = event.getNewBestSolution();
```

4) convert it to XML - e.g. use the Xstream stuff already in Optaplanner

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
xStream.processAnnotations(xStreamAnnotatedClasses);
String xml = xstream.toXML(solution);
```

There you are.

Comment: Do you know how to produce a result XML when optaplanner finds a feasible solution in the nurse scheduling case?

Comment: added to my answer how to make an xml. To check if it is feasible just check the score of the solution.